# Copying and modifying a immutable instance

Tags: python, properties, immutability, private

I'm trying to design a immutable class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 123

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
```

Now, I want to be able to "set" `foo`, by returning a copy of the instance, with the attribute modified:

```
import copy
[...]
    def set_foo(self, value):
        self_copy = copy.copy(self)
        self_copy._foo = value
        return self_copy
```

This means I have to change a private property of a variable. I know this is not frowned upon ("we're all adults here"), but seems less than ideal, and `pylint` complains.

Is there a better way to do this?